# Android OpenGL loading textures eats massive amounts of memory

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm building a live wallpaper in Android using OpenGL ES 2.0, and it's really just a bunch of textured rectangles floating in space. My problem is that for some reason loading these textures is consuming way more memory than is remotely reasonable. My largest image is 2078 kb, I'm only loading about 6-7 mb worth of images, and according to the Settings->Developer options->Running Services data my app is using 1.3 GB of memory.

When I remove the texture loading, my problem seems to go away (33 mb of memory), and it doesn't seem to matter if I actually draw the textures or not. I'm not entirely sure  if

code snippet of my texture loading code:

```
        Bitmap bmp = sceneSetter.getTexture(DataCodes.ROOM, DataCodes.FOUR_EIGHTY_P, DataCodes.BLUR_NONE);
    // Bind texture to texturename
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturenames[0]);
    // Set filtering
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    //clamp texture to edge of shape
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);

    //texture 1
    bmp = sceneSetter.getTexture(DataCodes.GIRL, DataCodes.FOUR_EIGHTY_P, DataCodes.BLUR_NONE);
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturenames[1]);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);
```

followed this at the end:

```
bmp.recycle();
```

sceneSetter retrieves the bitmap from resources like this:

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.testimage);
```

Edit: So, I'm testing this on a Samsung S7, but when I ran it on an Xperia Z3 compact it 'only' takes 154 MB of memory. This is still a lot, but dramatically less than the 1.3GB that the S7 is using.

Comment: What are the image dimensions in pixels?

Comment: I've got multiple images with varying image sizes. I've got a 1920 x 942,1191 x 892, 682 x 920 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking one of your texture sizes as an example, a 1191x892 will often be rounded up to next power of two dimensions in terms of space taken, so that's equivalent to 2048x1024. It looks like you're probably loading as 888/8888 which take 32-bits per pixel, so that's 2048*1024*4=8388608, then you probably have mipmaps too, which is an extra 33%, 8388608*1.33=11156848, which is close to 11MB for just one texture.

You haven't provided enough detail to work out if this can explain the 1.3GB you've seen, but it probably explains at least the 154MB.

I would look into ETC1 compression or 565/4444 formats and try choosing smarter texture dimensions.